# Is it possible to use CUDA parallelizing this nested for loop?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I want to speed up this nested for loop, just start learn CUDA, how could I use CUDA to parallel this c++ code ?

```
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int nbint = 2;
    int hits = 20;
    int nbinp = 2;
    float _theta, _phi, _l, _m, _n, _k = 0, delta = 5;
    float x[20],y[20],z[20],a[20],t[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; ++i)
    {
        y[i] = rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; ++i)
    {
        z[i] = rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 100);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < hits; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 100);
    }
    float maxforall = 1e-6;
    float theta0;
    float phi0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbint; i++)
    {
        _theta = (0.5 + i)*delta;
        for (int j = 0; j < nbinp; j++)
        {
            _phi = (0.5 + j)*delta / _theta;
            _l = sin(_theta* PI / 180.0)*cos(_phi* PI / 180.0);
            _m = sin(_theta* PI / 180.0)*sin(_phi* PI / 180.0);
            _n = cos(_theta* PI / 180.0);
            for (int k = 0; k < hits; k++)
            {
                _k = -(_l*x[k] + _m*y[k] + _n*z[k]);
                t[k] = a[k] - _k;   
            }

            qsort(t, 0, hits - 1);
            float max = t[0];
            for (int k = 0; k < hits; k++)
            {
                if (max < t[k])
                    max = t[k];
            }
            if (max > maxforall)
            {
                maxforall = max;
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to put innermost for loop and the sort part(maybe the whole nested loop) into parallel. After sort those array I found the maximum of all arrays. I use  maximum to simplify the code. The reason I need sort is that maximum represent 
here is a continuous time information(all arrays contain time information). The sort part make those time from lowest to highest. Then I compare the a specific time interval(not a single value). The compare process almost like I choose maximum but with a continuous interval not a single value.

Comment: what are you calculating here? how big are `nbint`, `nbinp` and `hits`? please post a [mcve] including a small numerical sample of your input data as well as the desired output.

Comment: First, I want to calculate the array t[k], then sort this array. The output I desired are nbint*nbinp sorted arrays.

Comment: do you want `20*2=40` arrays or a single array with `40` elements? why is the sorting performed inside the loops? the algorithm is still unclear to me

Comment: I want to 15*72 sorted arrays each of them have 2000 elements.

Comment: what do you do with those arrays afterwards?

Comment: The elements inside array are time information I want to return a time interval. So I can compare those interval.

Comment: After I sorted those arrays, some of elements inside the arrays almost the same(difference is very small). Ultimately I want one array which have the most close elements.

Comment: please update your question with all the information you have given in the comments, please also describe the postprocessing which you perform after receiving the sorted arrays as this might be much parallelizable as well (a small numerical example would help as well)

Comment: is this line really correct? it overwrites `k` which is used in the next line as the index: `k = -(l*x[k] + m*y[k] + n*z[k]);`

Comment: Thanks man. It too late in my country I'll update the question as soon as I go to my office tomorrow. Please check this question tomorrow. Thanks~~

Comment: I update my question. I write small numerical example. In practice the most complex part is compute t[k] and sort those arrays.

Comment: so the result of the algorithm is a single scalar (`maxforall`)? why do you have to sort the arrays at all if you just want to determine the max value?

Comment: Because after sort there is a complex filter condition(it's a physics process to filter the cosmic ray) I just use the maxforall to represent the similar process which makes the code more clearly.

Comment: is the "complex filter condition" both commutative and associative?

Comment: yes.  almost same process like "maxforall"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 3 nested loops calculate `nbint*nbinp*hits` values. Since each of those values is **independent** from each other, all values can be calculated in parallel.

You stated in your comments that you have a commutative and associative "filter condition" which reduces the output to a single scalar value. This can be exploited to avoid sorting and storing the temporary values. Instead, we can calculate the values on-the-fly and then apply a parallel reduction to determine the end result.

This can be done in "raw" CUDA, below I implemented this idea using thrust. The main idea is to run `grid_op` `nbint*nbinp*hits` times in parallel. In order to find out the three original "loop indices" from the single scalar index which is passed to `grid_op` the algorithm from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142417/4d-position-from-1d-index) is used.

`thrust::transform_reduce` performs the on-the-fly transformation and the subsequent parallel reduction (here `thrust::maximum` is used as a substitute).

```
#include <cmath>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>

// ### BEGIN utility for demo ####
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/random.h>

thrust::host_vector<float> random_vector(const size_t N)
{
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> u01(0.0f, 1.0f);
    thrust::host_vector<float> temp(N);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        temp[i] = u01(rng);
    }
    return temp;
}
// ### END utility for demo ####

template <typename... Iterators>
thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<Iterators...>> zip(Iterators... its)
{
    return thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(its...));
}

template <typename ZipIterator>
class grid_op
{
public:
    grid_op(ZipIterator zipIt, std::size_t dim1, std::size_t dim2) : zipIt(zipIt), dim1(dim1), dim2(dim2){}

    __host__ __device__
    float operator()(std::size_t index) const
    {
        const auto coords = unflatten_3d_index(index, dim1, dim2);
        const auto values = zipIt[thrust::get<2>(coords)]; 
        const float delta = 5;
        const float _theta = (0.5f + thrust::get<0>(coords))*delta;
        const float _phi = (0.5f + thrust::get<1>(coords))*delta / _theta;
        const float _l = sin(_theta* M_PI / 180.0)*cos(_phi* M_PI / 180.0);
        const float _m = sin(_theta* M_PI / 180.0)*sin(_phi* M_PI / 180.0);
        const float _n = cos(_theta* M_PI / 180.0);
        const float _k = -(_l*thrust::get<0>(values) + _m*thrust::get<1>(values) + _n*thrust::get<2>(values));
        return (thrust::get<3>(values) - _k);   
    }

private:
    __host__ __device__
    thrust::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t, std::size_t>
    unflatten_3d_index(std::size_t index, std::size_t dim1, std::size_t dim2) const
    {
        // taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142417/4d-position-from-1d-index
        std::size_t x = index % dim1;
        std::size_t y = ( ( index - x ) / dim1 ) %  dim2;
        std::size_t z = ( ( index - y * dim1 - x ) / (dim1 * dim2) );
        return thrust::make_tuple(x,y,z);
    }

    ZipIterator zipIt;
    std::size_t dim1;
    std::size_t dim2;
};

template <typename ZipIterator>
grid_op<ZipIterator> make_grid_op(ZipIterator zipIt, std::size_t dim1, std::size_t dim2)
{
    return grid_op<ZipIterator>(zipIt, dim1, dim2);
}

int main()
{
    const int nbint = 3;
    const int nbinp = 4;
    const int hits = 20;
    const std::size_t N = nbint * nbinp * hits;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_x = random_vector(hits);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_y = random_vector(hits);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_z = random_vector(hits);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_a = random_vector(hits);

    auto zipIt = zip(d_x.begin(), d_y.begin(), d_z.begin(), d_a.begin());
    auto countingIt = thrust::counting_iterator<std::size_t>(0);
    auto unary_op = make_grid_op(zipIt, nbint, nbinp);
    auto binary_op = thrust::maximum<float>();
    const float init = 0;

    float max = thrust::transform_reduce(
        countingIt, countingIt+N,
        unary_op,
        init,
        binary_op
    );

    std::cout << "max = " << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Your answer was very helpful. I'll check on programming guide learn more about  thrust and the index part is very helpful too. Maybe it's my misunderstand about the commutative and associative(sorry for that), but I really need the sort part here. Could I do it include the sorting?

Comment: @Alex sure, you could add the sorting, but you won't be able to do any on the fly reduction then, so performance will be much lower. You should really edit your question to show **why** you need to sort.

Comment: I edit my question show you why I need sort part. Hope you can understand or I can draw a picture about this. Thanks~

Comment: How could I add the sorting part? Even sacrifice the performance. In my program the sorting part is the most time consuming part.

Comment: I worry about the cost of the `%` in the function `unflatten_3d_index`. Division and modulus are expensive. (In the case above, maybe there is no problem with modulus, the `sin` and `cos` are more expensive.)