# Use an array with non-static size inside of a class

Tags: c++

I want to use a class that can store a value for me inside of a 4d array (`Matrix`). I want to use`SetSize` in order to set the size of the `Matrix` from my `main` function.

```
class Value{
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    //sets the values
    void SetSize(long Sizea, int Sizeb, int Sizec, int Sized){
        a = Sizea;
        b = Sizeb;
        c = Sizec;
        d = Sized;
    };

    double Matrix[a][b][c][d];

    void Putavalueinside (double input, long Positiona, long Positionb, long Positionc, long Positiond) {
        Matrix[Positiona][Positionb][Positionc][Positiond] = input;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //makes a class object
    Value Test;

    //sets the size
    Test.SetSize(3, 4, 5, 6);

    //gives the Matrix a value
    Test.Putavalueinside(10, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    //prints it to the consol
    std::cout << Test.Matrix[0][0][0][0];
}
```

However, the program does not compile and gives me the error:
`|15|error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Value::a'|`

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: `double Matrix[Positiona][Positionb][Positionc][Positiond] = input;` why the double at the beginning?

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo. Thanks. The problem still persists however.

Comment: You declare the field member `double Matrix[a][b][c][d];` depending on others field members (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) that are not instantiated yet. This is the error.

Comment: But can I instantiate them from the class itself somehow?

Comment: Please provide the definition of Matrix.

Comment: @MFnx It's in the class: `double Matrix[a][b][c][d];`.

Comment: a b c d must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways to solve this.  If you want to keep the array, then you need to move the dimension sizes from being constructor parameters to being template parameters.  Template parameters are known at compile time and can be used to create an array.  That would look like

```
template <size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, size_t d>
class Value{
    public:
    double Matrix[a][b][c][d]{};

    void Putavalueinside (double input, long Positiona, long Positionb, long Positionc, long Positiond) {
        Matrix[Positiona][Positionb][Positionc][Positiond] = input;
    }
};

int main()
{

    //makes a class object
    Value<3,4,5,6> Test;

    //gives the Matrix a value
    Test.Putavalueinside(10, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    //prints it to the consol
    std::cout << Test.Matrix[0][0][0][0];

}
```

If you don't know what the sizes will be at compile time then you are going to need to do some dynamic memory allocation.  To handle this you can use a `std::vector` as the storage type of the matrix and then you can use math to pretend it is a 4d structure.  That would look like

```
class Value{
public:
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    size_t c;
    size_t d;
    std::vector<double> Matrix;
    Value(size_t a_, size_t b_, size_t c_, size_t d_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_), d(d_), Matrix(a_ * b_ * c_ * d_) {}


    void Putavalueinside (double input, long Positiona, long Positionb, long Positionc, long Positiond) {
        Matrix[Positiona + Positionb * a + Positionc * a * b + Positiond * a * b * c] = input;
    }
    double Getvalueinside (long Positiona, long Positionb, long Positionc, long Positiond) {
        return Matrix[Positiona + Positionb * a + Positionc * a * b + Positiond * a * b * c];
    }
};

int main()
{

    //makes a class object
    Value Test(3,4,5,6);

    //gives the Matrix a value
    Test.Putavalueinside(10, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    //prints it to the consol
    std::cout << Test.Getvalueinside(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
```

---

The formula for flattening an n-dimension array can be found here: [4D position from 1D index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142417/4d-position-from-1d-index)

Comment: I do not know the size at the compile time (it is determined by a .csv file later on). The second example gives me:

`|29|error: invalid types '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type {aka double}[int]' for array subscript|`

Comment: @KGB91 Sorry about that.  I forgot to fix the matrix access.  The updated code now compiles.

Comment: @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica .Thanks, it was very good solution by using templates , great idea

Comment: I'm wonderig if the opposite order, like `Matrix[i_d + d * (i_c + c * (i_b + b * i_a))]`, would be more "idiomatic" in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a member array (as well as all automatic or static arrays) must be a compile time constant. So, what you're trying is not possible.

In order to have an array with non-static size, you must allocate the array dynamically. I recommend using `std::vector` to do the allocation.

Unfortunately, dynamic allocation means that you can only use a one dimensional array (only the outermost dimension of dynamic array may be determined at runtime). This is not a big deal however; the memory of a multi dimensional array is just as flat as the single dimensional array; this just means that you have to calculate the index instead of the compiler doing it for you.

Here is an example layout of a 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 array laid flat:

```
0123456789abcdef <- flat index
0000000011111111 <- dimension a
0000111100001111 <- dimension b
0011001100110011 <- dimension c
0101010101010101 <- dimension d
```

Comment: It's not possible ?,  some IDE like code blocks build this code successfully , it just not good use it even using code blocks, but still possible .

Comment: @Prof.Mo It's not possible (to have non-dynamic arrays with non-constant size) in standard C++.

Comment: Yeah you are right , but some IDEs allows you to use non constant size by handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you should use hardly, if ever, C-style dynamic arrays (i.e. using `new`). You should define your `Matrix` as

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> Matrix;
```

(I know it is ugly, but thats how it is, you should probably add a `using matrix_t = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>>;` somwhere, so you only have to type that once). Then initialize this vector in the constructor.

As constructor use

```cpp
Value(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, size_t d) :
 Matrix({a, {b, {c,std::vector<double>(d,0.0)}}})
{}
```

You can also us a one-dimensional `vector` of size `a*b*c*d` and calculate the index in this array from the 4 indices in the matrix.

Comment: `Matrix[a][b][c][d] = val;` (in the multidimensional case)

Comment: Multiple dimensions vectors are a trap.  Do not us them for anything that need performance.

Comment: When I try `std::cout << Test.Matrix[0][0][0][0];`I get rror:

`#0 0x4043c0 std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > > >::operator[](this=0x0, __n=0) (c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:781)
#1 0x403d49 Value::Putavalueinside(this=0x62fef4, input=10, Positiona=0, Positionb=0, Positionc=0, Positiond=0)`

Comment: gotta love this c++ error messages...^^ Did you copy my definition exactly? It looks a bit like the Matrix lacks a dimension

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica You are certainly right. But I think they are easier to read and if you _really_ need performance, you should use some linear algebra library.

Comment: @KGB91 You need to **initialize** the 4 dimensional `std::vector` which is quite painful (4 nested `for` loops). Do remember than trying to access an out of bound element is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I just did: 

`std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> Matrix;

        void Putavalueinside (double input, long Positiona, long Positionb, long Positionc, long Positiond) {
            Matrix[Positiona][Positionb][Positionc][Positiond] = input;
        }`

Comment: @Fareanor That is not quite right @4 for-loops, you can do it as 
```matrix_t Matrix = {a, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>{b, std::vector<std::vector<double>>{c, std::vector<double>{d}}}};
```
but i agree, it's still a mess.

Comment: @n314159 Right ^^

Comment: @KGB91 Exactly, it is not enough, you need to initialize your Matrix or at least resize it before trying to get any element. If you don't, the matrix will be empty. You are trying to access an element your never created, this is why you got an error.

Comment: @Fareanor Ok, how do I do that?

Comment: actually, this works `matrix_t v {a, {b, {c,std::vector<double>(d,0.0)}}};`@Fareanor, @KGB91 I will change my answer to show this

Answer (score 1):

Your array sizes need to be known at compile time if you want to avoid dynamic allocation. Possible implementation:

```
template <size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, size_t d>
class Value
{
    double Matrix[a][b][c][d];
};
```

Also, consider using `std::array`. If you know the sizes only at runtime, you need to allocate dynamically (with `new`). Even better, use `std::vector` (which uses heap memory).

Answer (score 0):

As you've written things, the field Value::Matrix must be allocated when you create a Value object, because its size determines the size of the Value object.  This size can't be changed later on.  (In fact, the size of an object needs to be a compile-time constant, so that it can be stack-allocated, made into arrays, etc.)

If you want something whose size is going to be determined at runtime, it needs to be heap-allocated, e.g. by using `new[]`.  (There are various ways of wrapping `new[]` with higher-level constructs so that you don't have to keep track and `delete[]` the result when you're done with it, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector`, but you should learn how to work with pointers first so you understand what these are even doing and why.)

Also, you need to take into account the fact that a multidimensional array in C++ is an array of pointers to arrays.  This is bad for performance due to extra indirection and poor cache locality, so you may want to implement things as a one-dimensional array under the hood.

Alternatively, if the size is known at compile time, it could be given as a template parameter:

```
template<int A, int B, int C, int D>
class Value
{
  int a = A;
  int b = B;
  int c = C;
  int d = D;

  double Matrix[A][B][C][D];

  //...
};

// ...

Value<3, 3, 2, 5> val;
```

Note that this still has the issues with multidimensional arrays mentioned above.

Comment: I will the size it when I make the class object. How do I use new? 

`double Matrix;`
`double Matrix = new ..`

?

Comment: Please don't say to use `new`.  `new` really doesn't have a place in C++ anymore.

Comment: If we were talking about production code I'd agree, but make_unique just wraps new under the hood and you shouldn't jump to doing things with smart pointers before understanding what pointers are.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Except in low-level library code which is implementing the higher level code, and a few other exceptional circumstances.  (I once had to use `new foo` rather than `make_unique<foo>` because `foo` had a private constructor.  The function I was calling this from was a friend, so `m_ptr = std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo);` compiled, but `m_ptr = std::make_unique<foo>();` didn't (because `make_unique` wasn't a friend).

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I disagree.  Use smart pointers until you are ready to learn about the nasty nitty gritty.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I don't mention cases like that since once you are doing things at that level, you should know when you actually can use new.